# Draw this loop in Postscript

Tags: adobe, postscript

Any idea how to draw this in Postscript using for loop and ifelse conditional?

My idea was to make a large red circle, then a smaller white circle and a smaller red circle again...
Also we can see that the color is getting darker so it should also be saved as a variable that gets darker.

```
50 50 translate
/coordinate_system {0.5 0.3 0 0 setcmykcolor 
gsave
2 setlinewidth 500 0 moveto 0 0 lineto 0 500 lineto stroke
grestore
gsave
0.3 setlinewidth
9 { 30 100 moveto 500 100 lineto stroke 0 50 translate } repeat
grestore
gsave
0.3 setlinewidth
10 { 100 20 moveto 100 500 lineto stroke 50 0 translate } repeat
grestore
gsave
/tekst 3 string def /Helvetica findfont 10 scalefont setfont
100 100 500 { /y exch def 5 y 2 sub moveto y tekst cvs show } for
90 100 500 { /x exch def x 5 moveto x 10 add tekst cvs show } for
grestore 
0 setgray } bind def
/s { mark pstack pop } def
coordinate_system
```

And this is the code so far...

```
100 100 translate

%100 -3 0 {{1 0 0 setrgbcolor exch 0 exch 0 360 arc stroke}{0 0 0 setrgbcolor exch 0 exch 0 360 arc stroke} ifelse} for
3 4 lt {1 0 0 setrgbcolor 0 0 50 0 360 arc stroke}{0 0 0 setrgbcolor 0 0 100 0 360 arc stroke} ifelse
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following code loops for `i = 1, 2, ..., 10`. I am using `i` to control the radius and color of the circle.

```
/i 1 def              

{
    i 0.1 mul 0 0 setrgbcolor        % RGB (i*0.1, 0, 0)
    i 10 gt { exit } if              % exit the loop if i > 10
    300 300                          % center at 300 300
    20 i mul                         % radius 20*i
    drawcircle
    /i i 1 add def                   % i = i + 1
} loop
```

`drawcircle` code:

```
/drawcircle                      % XO YO R 
{
    newpath
    0 360 arc
    closepath
    stroke
} bind def

3 setlinewidth
```

My output (cropped a bit) is:

[image: concentric circles of darker shades]

Comment: Your loop code could be simpler by using a `for` loop. Eg. `1 1 10{ \i exch def ... }for`.